# Jmeter-Ant xslt-report: BUILD FAILED Test.jtl does not exist error although i have Test.jtl

Tags: performance, testing, xslt, ant, jmeter

I am trying to run my Test.jmx file through below ant cmd:
*C:\apache-ant-1.10.1-bin\bin>ant*

I got the following error:

```html
C:\apache-ant-1.10.1-bin\bin>ant
Buildfile: C:\apache-ant-1.10.1-bin\bin\build.xml

run:
     [echo] funcMode = false
   [jmeter] Executing test plan: C:\apache-ant-1.10.1-bin\bin\Test.jmx ==> C:\apache-ant-1.10.1-bin\bin\Test.jtl

_message_xalan:

xslt-report:

BUILD FAILED
C:\apache-ant-1.10.1-bin\bin\build.xml:124: input file C:\apache-ant-1.10.1-bin\bin\Test.jtl does not exist

Total time: 4 seconds

C:\apache-ant-1.10.1-bin\bin>
```

I fixed this issue by creating a new Test.jtl file.

Now I am getting this error:

```html
C:\apache-ant-1.10.1-bin\bin>ant -Dtestpath=C:\apache-ant-1.10.1-bin\bin\ -Dtest=Test
Buildfile: C:\apache-ant-1.10.1-bin\bin\build.xml

run:
     [echo] funcMode = false
   [jmeter] Executing test plan: C:\apache-ant-1.10.1-bin\bin\Test.jmx ==> C:\apache-ant-1.10.1-bin\bin\Test.jtl

_message_xalan:

xslt-report:
     [xslt] Processing C:\apache-ant-1.10.1-bin\bin\Test.jtl to C:\apache-ant-1.10.1-bin\bin\Test.html
     [xslt] Loading stylesheet C:\apache-ant-1.10.1-bin\bin\jmeter-results-report_21.xsl
     [xslt] C:\apache-ant-1.10.1-bin\bin\Test.jtl:1:1: Fatal Error! Premature end of file.
     [xslt] Failed to process C:\apache-ant-1.10.1-bin\bin\Test.jtl

BUILD FAILED
C:\apache-ant-1.10.1-bin\bin\build.xml:124: Fatal error during transformation using C:\apache-ant-1.10.1-bin\bin\jmeter-results-report_21.xsl: Premature end of file.; SystemID: file:/C:/apache-ant-1.10.1-bin/bin/Test.jtl; Line#: 1; Column#: 1

Total time: 3 seconds
```

Comment: I deleted the old file and created new Test.jtl and i see the following C:\apache-ant-1.10.1-bin\bin\build.xml:124: Fatal error during transformation using C:\apache-ant-1.10.1-bin\bin\jmeter-results-report_21.xsl: Premature end of file.; SystemID: file:/C:/apache-ant-1.10.1-bin/bin/Test.jtl; Line#: 1; Column#: 1

Comment: delete Test.jtl before you execute the test

Answer (score 3):

Actually, the correct answer is [here](http://www.techknowstudy.com/2017/06/jmeter-and-ant-integration-errors.html). Just need to remove the comments from these lines:

```
<jvmarg value="-Xincgc"/>
<jvmarg value="-Xmx128m"/>
<jvmarg value="-Dproperty=value"/>
<jmeterarg value="-qextra.properties"/>
```

in the `extracts\build.xml` file.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely your JMeter test is failing therefore it doesn't generate result file. I would suggest amending your  target like

```
    <jmeter
        jmeterhome="${jmeter.home}"
        testplan ="${testpath}/${test}.jmx"
        resultlog="${testpath}/${test}.jtl"
        jmeterlogfile="${testpath}/jmeter.log>
```

in *build.xml* file. The last line will "tell" the JMeter Ant task to generate *jmeter.log* file under the `${testpath}`, you should be able to figure out what goes wrong by looking into this file.

References:

- [JMeter Ant Task Parameters](https://github.com/jfifield/ant-jmeter#parameters)
- [Five Ways To Launch a JMeter Test without Using the JMeter GUI](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui)

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @Dmitri T answer jtl file is created only if you execute at least 1 Sample, so it won't be created in the following cases:

1. Your test plan failed and Stopped before executing Sampler
2. Your test doesn't contain Samplers
3. Your configuration is wrong and no thread were executed ( for example Thread number is 0)

You can try to execute/view/debug in GUI mode and check what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

use "resultlogdir" instead of "resultlog"
so change the build.xml  like this:

```
<jmeter
jmeterhome="${jmeter.home}"
testplan ="${testpath}/${test}.jmx"
resultlogdir="${testpath}/log">
```

and also the "in" property in  :
   in="${testpath}/log/${test}.jtl"

I have no idea how to explain why, but it worked in my computer